# jQuery Mobile Scrollview

Tags: jquery, mobile, scrollview

So I'm trying to make a scrollable list:

```
<div data-role="content-primary" class="list" style="height:100%; overflow:scroll" data-scroll="y">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="mainList" >
        <asp:Repeater ID="expList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="expList_ItemDataBound" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="opener" runat="server" id="lItem" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200)">
                    <div id="divPic" runat="server" class="pic">
                        <h2><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litName"></asp:Literal></h2>
                        <p><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litDesc"></asp:Literal></p>
                        <input type="hidden" Id="brand" runat="server"/>
                        <input type="hidden" Id="cat" runat="server"/>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</div>
```

enclosed in: <.section class="ex_list" style="float: right; width:70%;overflow:hidden"> tag

I use following scripts:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js

http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview.js

In addition to jqm and jq. Problem is that on PC scrolling doesn't work (yet it's not so bad), but on iPad whole site is being scrolled in addition to listview. User can also scroll OVER the site and see gray bg, until safari stops scrolling.

EDIT: In addition these 2 JS's make 'toggleClass()' jQuery function not work.

Comment: and what is the outcome you were expecting?

Comment: Except for working 'toggleClass()' function, well I wanted only listview to be scrollable. Or if whole page is supposed to be scrollable, at least it shouldn't scroll above the page, showing gray background... You've probably noticed it's part of ASP control, Master Page has nothing like data-scroll, yet it scrolls:'(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just finished implementing this on android(2.2 and 3.2) and on iphone (not ipad) for scrollview to work properly, you need to include the [css](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/jquery.mobile.scrollview.css) file, and the [jquery easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) script.

Scripts must be included in this order:

1. jquery
2. jquery.mobile
3. jquery.easing
4. jquery.mobile.scrollview
5. scrollview

The css file gives you the scroll bars, [jquery.easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) gives the smooth animation (an impressive project by itself), jquery.mobile.scrollview does the heavy lifting, scrollview scrapes the page and adds enough markup for the scrollview to take over.

I am sure I don't need to tell you that it's is 'Experimental' for a reason (bizarre behaviour while scrolling through a listview, it also breaks the ability to click on buttons and in text areas on chromium-browser - I haven't tested other browsers), however I have found very few problems with it on mobile devices. I really like that it enables me to keep the tabs at the top of the page all the time. Nesting many scrollviews is pretty cool as well.

I can't say that I have noticed any problems with toggleClass function, however that might have something to do with scrollview going through and adding markup.

NOTE: As of the most recent version of jQuery mobile rc2, the buttons and text inputs should work.

**EDIT**

As of jQuery Mobile 1.1.0, it is [recommended](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/) to use the [fixed headers](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) using the `data-position="fixed"` attribute in the header (or footer) and completely remove scrollview.

I have tried this myself and it works much better (for Android 2.2+ and iOS5 - BlackBerry OS not tested by me, but the blog claims it should work for BB7). It runs faster and smoother than the js solution and has fewer graphical bugs. Be sure to remove all the extra js, css and all references to `data-scroll` as it interferes/breaks everything.

For unsupported versions and OS's you might still need the scrollview js/css etc, but in my experience the places that don't support the fixed headers were too slow to run the js version anyway.

Comment: I'm also struggeling with a scrollable list view in my master thesis. I tried the links you provided, but they don't seem to work anymore. Could you please help me with this? I also looked up in the jQuery Mobile Library but it seems that the scrollview isn't documented anywhere. I tried to solve it with frames, but that doesn't work somehow.

Comment: Try looking at the links in the edit. Using the latest version of jqm all you should need to do is use the `data-position="fixed"` property in the header or footer to prevent it from scrolling with the contents.

Comment: Thats what i did and it worked. But i was wondering if there is a possibility of using frames. BR

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do. I have not seen frames used with jqm (probably due to cross platform compatibility/appearance/performance issues). Sorry I can't be more helpful. Perhaps if you had a more detailed explanation, or opened a new question you would find more helpful answers.

Comment: Hi CoatedMoose. Thanks for the explanation. No, i don't want to raise a new question. When you tell me, that its not gonna work for the reasons you just gave, than i'm fine. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Nice thread here, like to contribute a small note:

If you like the grey areas in Safari to disappear in jQuery mobile pages when scrolled, you can use:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Also more importantly, this will enable you to work with offline databases more efficiently, because normally the UI (touchmove event) interrupts SqlLite DB functions on mobile devices, this way interruption is avoided.

Comment: this will disable scrolling horizontally and vertically. Not a good practice I suppose.