# Need to scroll the page when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, cordova

Hi i have developed application in android using phonegap and jquerymobile.When the keyboard is visible while typing in textbox,the footer comes above the keyboard and textboxes are resized.

Here is my code added in android Manifestfile:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Now the footer is hidden when keyboard is visible and also textbox is good.But i cannot able to scroll the page when keyboard is visible.For eg: if i have many textboxes and i need to type in last textbox,then i need to make the keyboard invisible and then focus the last one.

Please help me to solve this problem.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I currently have the same Problem. Did you solved it yet, or did you find a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

use a scrollview in your layout and in manifest change to  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"`

Comment: Thanks.I have tried this but page is not getting scrolled properly till the end of the page...Please guide me.

Comment: i am not an expert in jquerymobile and phonegap but after some searching was able to find this.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254761/jquery-mobile-scrollview .. do try GOODLUCK :)

Comment: But its not jquery problem,only android problem

Comment: ScrollView in your layout is the solution to this... could you please post your code of your layout

Comment: which layout you are asking?in android

Comment: yes is there any xml layout like in android, or is it html/javascript based .. what ever edit and post in the question