# Android browser auto scroll to top when select textfield and keyboard hide issue

Tags: android, html, css, browser, webkit-transform

I am working on responsive website. On `Samsung Gallaxy SII` and `DUOS` Android browser scroll to top when giving input to any form fields and keyboard hide.

Where use this or not -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

This issue is only on Android default browser not on Firefox, Opera and Chrome

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254761/jquery-mobile-scrollview. You should make scroll view as parent view...

Comment: I want to stop auto scroll. No Scrolling added